# Disk I/O degradation with concurrent writes to the same file

Tags: hard-disk, disk

I am benchmarking concurrent disk I/O from multiple processes, and I get very different results when writing to the same file, or to different files. Because I am using O_DIRECT, I was not expecting this difference.

The script that was used:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
nprocs=$1
for i in $(seq $nprocs)
do
    target=test_file$i
    [[ "${2:-}" == "same" ]] && target=test_file
    echo $(date) - Run $i/$nprocs $(dd if=/dev/zero of=$target bs=2k count=128000 oflag=direct 2>&1) &
done
```

The results:

```
# iostat while running: sh mkfile.sh 10
vg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.39    0.00    9.62   12.09    0.00   77.89

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00 11016.00     0.00 33409.50     6.07    81.36    0.12    0.00    0.12   0.09 100.00


# iostat while running: sh mkfile.sh 10 same
vg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.51    0.00    7.95    4.87    0.00   86.67

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00 7780.00     0.00 16362.00     4.21     0.75    0.10    0.00    0.10   0.10  74.90
```

The difference can be seen on the W/S, 11016.00 (multifile) and 7780.00 (singlefile). Because dd is using O_DIRECT, regardless of writing to the same physical area I do not expect to have any kind of kernel level locking, avgqu-sz is low and %util does not reach 100% so I am unable to physical I/O contention either.

I must be missing something really trivial here :)

Any idea on the reason for the much lower IOPS rate ?

Comment: Let me guess, SATA consumer grade hard disk? Abraços

Comment: Not really, this finding was with enterprise class SAN storage on VMWare ESX, I was able to reproduce it with my own SATA SDD, so this is not hardware specific.

Comment: And neither are good examples *I think*.....consumer SATAs and iSCSI are not the faster alternatives out there. I would try it in a raw server raw grade disk to test the theory.

Comment: This is not HW related, the I/O requests are blocked at the OS level, svctime is low and there are no requests beeing queded on the driver path.